# How to sequence the messages inside Anypoint MQ

Tags: database, queue, mulesoft, anypoint-mq

I have a requirement in Mulesoft to subscribe to anypoint mq and get messages and then create a table which in the end of flow will be deleted, so what is happening is I have given fetch size as 10 so it is picking the first message and creates the table and before this message is completed, another message from queue is picked and it tries to create a table which is failing with error ‘there is already an object named table in the database’. Is there a way to gather all 10 messages process them at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably asking the wrong question to solve the issue. Even if you read more messages with fetch size you can not avoid more messages to arrive. Instead use the `maxConcurrency` attribute of the flow to limit it to only 1 concurrent execution.

Example

```xml
<flow name="myFlow" maxConcurrency="1">
... some operation that should not be executed concurrently
</flow>
```

See the [documentation of maxConcurrency](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/tuning-backpressure-maxconcurrency) for reference.

Comment: I wanted to check this because we will have to create the temporary table and delete it for every message. If we can limit the messages to few and create the table for few messages at a time to store in db.

Comment: Restricting the concurrency will guarantee that the flow won't execute in parallel if another message arrives. This is the only way to guarantee that. The Anypoint MQ connector configuration will help only with the number of messages read at once. Please read the documentation of fetch usage: https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-mq-connector/4.x/anypoint-mq-listener

Comment: we have 10 messages in queue and we give 1 as max local messages while polling(30secs) from anypoint mq, if the first message is not executed completely in 30secs , it will start polling and pick next message again right?